Implementing SLAM-GDM for Gas Distribution Mapping in ROS2
Implementing SLAM-GDM for Gas Distribution Mapping in ROS2
Hi everyone,
For the past two weeks, I’ve been exploring how to implement SLAM combined with Gas Distribution Mapping (SLAM-GDM) using sensor data. My goal is to map gas concentration levels based on the robot’s position, using colors to represent different concentration levels on the map.
I came across a few papers that demonstrate a similar approach:



Paper 1
Paper 2
Paper 3

I’m still new to this and could use some guidance, I’m familiar with implementing SLAM on its own. However, I’m unsure how to combine it with gas sensor readings to create a concentration map that visualizes gas levels across the mapped area. Does anyone know if there are any existing ROS2 packages for SLAM-GDM or similar implementations? Or any advice on how to approach this?
Thanks!
